# Taking Jacobian for DVL aided inertial navigation measurement function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, jacobian, kalman-filter

I am looking into an inertial navigation filter implementation and I would like to take advantage of a doppler velocity log (DVL) for the velocity measurements. This requires me to take the Jacobian of the measurement function, suppose my state vector is
$$
x =  \begin{bmatrix}q &p &v \end{bmatrix}
$$
for quaternion orientation, position, and velocity. The error state vector is thus
$$
\delta x = \begin{bmatrix} \delta\rho &\delta p & \delta v\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\delta\rho$ is the attitude error about the three cartesian axes.

The measurement function is thus
$$
y = \hat{R}_{n}^{b} v^{n}
$$
where $R_{n}^{b}=(R_{b}^{n})^{T}$ is the rotation matrix resulting from the quaternion $q$. This is the case because the DVL measures velocity with respect to body frame and the estimate is given with respect to NED frame. I am in doubt about how to take the derivative
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial \delta x}
$$
where $h=\hat{R}_{n}^{b} v^{n}$

I understand the derivative can be broken into the chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial \delta x} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial\delta x} 
$$
but I am not sure how to begin evaluating this derivative?

Comment: How do you define the error for the orientation? Additive $\hat{q} = q + \delta \rho$ or multiplicative $\hat{q} = q\,\delta\rho$ using the [Hamiltonian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Hamilton_product), such that the orientation error would be zero if $\delta \rho = 1$, and $q$, $\hat{q}$ and $\delta\rho$ are unit quaternions?

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific, I am defining the attitude error such that $q = \rho \otimes \hat{q}$, so the attitude error represents the global error in the orientation and is compensated by taking the quaternion product.